# 2nd Ucanaccess transaction not always being pushed to MDB

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, ucanaccess

I am using Ucanaccess-3.0.2 with JPA (EclipseLink). For most use cases it works just fine. But I have one scenario in which I

1. start a transaction
2. update a row
3. commit the transaction
4. start a new transaction
5. update the same row again
6. commit the 2nd transaction.

At that point the data from the 2nd transaction is visible upon querying (in a new transaction), but if I close EntityManagerFactory and open the MDB the 2nd transaction hasn't been persisted.

The entity is described by

```
/**
 * Primary Key of an Entry.
 */
@Embeddable
public class EntryPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "Event", updatable = false)
    Integer eventId;

    @Column(name = "Athlete_no", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    Integer athleteId;
}

/**
 * My entity.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "Entry")
public class Entry {

    @EmbeddedId
    private EntryPK privateKey;

    @Column(name = "Event", updatable = true)
    private Integer eventId;

    @Column(name = "Athlete_no", updatable = true)
    private Integer athleteId;

    @Column(name = "Time")
    private Double time; // In seconds

    @Column(name = "DQCODE")
    private String dqCode;
}
```

NB the transaction will persist if the record was empty or if the record is being cleared. But if the record already has some data in it then it doesn't always persist. Its 100% reproducible, not intermittent. But the prior state of the data in a record has an impact on whether the next commit will persist to the MDB.

Eg Starting with `Entry{eventId=1, athleteId=1}` and updating to `Entry{eventId=1, athleteId=1, time=12.34}` will work. If I then update to `Entry{eventId=1, athleteId=1, time=23.45}` it will persist according to a query on the JPA EntityManager, but **will not** persist to the MDB. But if I instead update to `Entry{eventId=1, athleteId=1, time=23.45, dqCode='XX'}` it **will** persist to the MDB.

Is this possibly because the change has been made to the intermediary HSQL DB and has not yet been written to the MDB?

If so, how do I ensure that the transaction is pushed to the MDB?

Answer (score 2):

OK, the solution is simple (thanks @GordThompson for the help).

While the transaction was being committed, I was not closing the EntityManager. So under some scenarios the transaction was being wound back.

Note to self: Always close the EntityManager.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you may have to close and re-open MS Access to see data persisted. UCanAccess uses [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) to update the Access database, and Jackcess directly modifies the database file without using the Access Database Engine. So, MS Access may not "see" the changes until it has been closed and re-opened.

If a commit has been called on UCanAccess it always flushes and persists data in the Access database. It is definitely not possible that flushing has been postponed, at least as far as the UCanAccess layer is concerned. Perhaps a review of the higher-level code may reveal a possible explanation for the behaviour you are experiencing.

Comment: The MDB is never open elsewhere at the time of the commits. We open it afterwards to check the result. The commit has clearly occurred according to the EntityManager, but is not getting to the MDB. I suspect that UCanAccess is discarding the secondary update because only a single column has changed and there is no primary key defined for the table.

Comment: In the meantime, are there another record identical to the the one checked for the update?

Comment: @William re: *"there is no primary key defined for the table"* - Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34250537/edit) your question to explain how you have configured your Entity. I just tried to recreate your issue and EclipseLink failed on startup with "Entity class [class com.example.so34250537.Todo] has no primary key specified." In cases like this a [mcve] is essential to understanding the issue.

Comment: @GordThompson I have updated the question, and included an example. There is a primary key defined  for the entity in JPA. What I meant is that the MS Access table has no explicit primary key index defined.

Comment: @jamadei No. No other record has been updated with that data. I have updated the question with some sample data and also the JPA definition.

Comment: @William - I am unable to recreate your issue with UCanAccess 3.0.3 using the test code [here](http://pastebin.com/GLrr4NnU). The second transaction does in fact get committed back to the .mdb database file, even when I only update the [time] column.

Comment: Thank you for your help @GordThompson. I have been looking at this code for the last 18 months and while I have been committing the transaction I have failed to see that I was not closing the EntityManager.